# Display client side people picker on modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, modal-dialog

I am trying to display client side people picker on modal dialog

HTML Code

```
 <div data-ng-model="vm.ex.siteOwner" id="peoplePickerDiv" ></div>
```

in the controller

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
// define controller

var controllerId = "siteInfo";
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    [ 'common', 'datacontext', 'spContext', siteInfo]);

function siteInfo( common, datacontext, spContext) {
    var vm = this;


       init();


function init(){
initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');    }

// setup the people picker
        function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {
            // set config options on the people picker
            var schema = {};
            schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User';
            schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
            schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
            schema['Width'] = '280px';

            // Render and initialize the picker.  
            SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
        }

}
}();
```

Unfortunately in the modal dialog the div is not Initializing the people picker input. I can see the people outside the modal dialog window.

Should I access the html id of the people picker of the  modal dialog in different way in the controller. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance